# ¿Cómo hacer que los caracteres en contraseña se vean con asteriscos en un inputbox?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2013

Quiero que al ingresar los datos en un inputbox (contraseña) estos no se muestren , es decir que se muestre asteriscos.

En C# por favor, algo similar a la propiedad del textbox (passwordchar).

Comment: pero si eso es lo que buscas. no estaria entendiendo que estas preguntando...

Comment: Que es un `inputbox` en C#?

Comment: Replantea la pregunta por que no se entiende, si puedes agregar tu código relevante seria de mucha utilidad

Comment: Por lo que intento entender lo que quiere es en un Inputbox, de esos que se abren como MessageBox, que en vez de aparecer el texto que aparezcan asteriscos.

Comment: Yo le entendí si. El lo que quiere que cuando se despliegue el inputbox y el usuario vaya a escribir en el cuadro de texto de dicho inputbox en lugar de aparecer letras aparezcan asteriscos

Answer (score 4):

Un TextBox tiene dos propiedades que te pueden servir para lo que preguntas: `UseSystemPasswordChar` y la que mencionas, `PasswordChar`

Si pones `UseSystemPasswordChar = True` usará el caracter que usa tu sistema operativo para enmascarar el texto, sin importar qué caracter escribas en `PasswordChar`. Si pones `UseSystemPasswordChar = False`, pero en `PasswordChar` le pones cualquier caracter, ése caracter lo usará para enmascarar el texto.

Espero te sirva de ayuda la respuesta.